# border-radius + overflow:hidden = thin black line

Tags: html, css

here is my issue:

[image]

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 66px;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cjW7Q/1/

Notice thin black line on the right side.
Any ideas how to get rid of it?

**UPDATE**

There is a lot of workarounds, but problem is that overflow:hidden doesn't work correctly. Imagine that instead of .inner I have an image, that I want to move around with transition using transform (for hardware acceleration). I'll try to update demo later.

Comment: How about `border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px;` ?

Comment: what exactly u expected?

Answer (score 1):

`<edit>`multiple bg mixing image and gradient can be used with animation too without extra markup **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/thDiG/)** `</edit>`

---

This is a commun defaut , you see it in FF too.

I would say , paint it the other way round : 
`.wrap` doesn't even need a bckground color.
http://jsfiddle.net/cjW7Q/2/

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 66px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
}
```

---

Else you can use a gradient and no inner element:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 66px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background:linear-gradient(to left,white 50%,black 50%);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjW7Q/6/)**

Comment: Yep, this can help, but only in this particular case. What if I have an image instead of .inner, and need to move that image from right to left. Problem is overflow:hidden doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @RomanPominov it is no problem , with mutiple background you can set image + gradient and cover one with the other . , it would even be the most flexible one , gradient can de any degres , not just 0deg and 90deg as a box does without transform. Do you need examples ?

Comment: but I can't animate backgrounds using transform (for hardware acceleration)

Comment: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/thDiG/ , what do you mean animate , it is not in your question on the first place ?

Comment: Yep, sorry. Didn't mention it. I updated question and will try to make demo later.

Comment: @RomanPominov okay , for animation check this : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/thDiG/ tune yourself position and size in order to get effect needed

Comment: Yes, but you can't use `transform` property for animation. It really better to do animation using `transform`. You get sub-pixel movement and hardware acceleration. Actually I hoped for fix, not workaround. Like border-right-width:0px, but working one. Maybe there is no such fix. I already did some workaround in my case.

Comment: @RomanPominov to trigger hardware acceleration , you can add transform:translate(1px,1px) an dposition:relative : top:-1px;left:-1px; i do not where is the problem or a transform:scale(1.0001), if you want to be smart with transform, do it fully :).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Work Around](http://jsfiddle.net/cjW7Q/3/)

```
.inner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 50%;
 bottom: 0;
 background: black;
}
```

Apply the same background of it's parent for the parent element (here there's no need of background at all)

Comment: @RomanPominov that'll work in this particular case if you want to create a shape like this, but not when this happens on a div to which you simply want to apply border-radius in specific corners..

Answer (score 0):

Add "border-right-width: 0px;" to .wrap.

Comment: It does not in Firefox :(

Comment: You are right. This is not a good solution, after trying a few different browsers.

Comment: I tried it right when this question was posted, won't work in safari 6.1

Comment: @GCyrillus firefox 28, mac os x 10.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS,

```
.wrap {
position: relative;
width: 200px; 
height: 66px;
background: black;
overflow: hidden;
border-top-left-radius: 100px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rs8tv/)

Answer (score -1):

```css
border:0px 
paddind : 10 px
background:#FFF
```

Comment: Please add details where to add this